# swift hiding navbar in mmdrawercontroller

Tags: ios, swift, mmdrawercontroller

I have created a slidout menu for kmy app with mmdrawercontroller from github.

It all works perfectly but i can't get rid of the nav bar at the top. it is overlapping part of my many but also shows up on all other pages. I need it gone. i have found the following code

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
```

But i have no idea where to place it. I tried it in appdelegate, in the leftsliderviewcontroller, in the button who invokes the mmdrawercontroller. But nothing seems to work.

Also in code that comes with the mmdrawercontroller i can't find anywhere a bool for this setting.

Can any one show me how to hide this navigationbar.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide your `UINavigationBar` in some `UIViewControllers` the you need to call `self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true` in your `viewWillAppear` like in the following way:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

And the above code hide your `UINavigationBar`. I hope this help you.